# Access-2013 Passing data from a textbox of one form to another form's autonumber textbox

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba

I am having an issue with passing data from a textbox of one form to another form's autonumber. I am also very new to Access DBs and I am trying to learn them and right now I am stumped.

What I mean by this is that when I double click in the list on the First form (`Form1`) I pass data from Form1 to Form2 and the rest of the variables will be updated, except for the variable `TI_ID`, since this is an autonumber. It is also the `primary key` as well and the data is taken from a query that is used with 3 tables.

This is the VB Event I have made for the double click.

```
Private Sub TI_List_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
DoCmd.OpenForm "ImportData"

Forms!ImportData.TI_ID = Me.TI_ID
Forms!ImportData.Know_ID = Me.Know_ID
Forms!ImportData.TI_Title = Me.TI_Title
```

It will complain and give me a runtime error

```
'438' Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

On Form 2, i have 3 text boxes as above and a ListBox, When you select s row in the list box, it automatically updates the textboxes up above. The issue is that again the other 2 text boxes (`Know_ID and TI_Title`) will update, but the `TI_ID` will not so if we change the title it will always save the data to the first `TI_ID` and then move to the next.

```
Private Sub SearchResults_Click()

TI_Title = SearchResults.Column(0)
'TI_ID = SearchResults.Column(1)
Know_ID = SearchResults.Column(2)


End Sub
```

As you can see the `TI_ID` part of the List_Box will not work as well and leads to problems.

I have noticed that on the Form Footer on Form2, I can move the record forward and back and even use the Search to find the number i want. This will also update the other fields. When I click a box that updates the record, it updates the correct record.

Is there a way that I could trick the double click to instead of trying to set the value, but to search for the data, that should have the identical number to the same field on the first one without a popup? Also if I can do this, can I do this with Form2's textbox to do the same thing? Is there an easier way that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a value to an Autonumber field (TB2.PK). It's an identity field. You can add a new record which includes the ID you want to retain.

```
Table 1 
MyKey1 (autonumber)

Table 2 
MyKey2 (autonumber) 
MyKey1 (value from Table 1)
```